# Close colotbox callback only if a button is clicked inside the colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I use

```
onClosed:function(){ window.location.reload(); }
```

option to reload the page after the colorbox is closed but I don't want to always perform the reload but only when a user clicks one HTML button inside the colorbox. Colorbox is closed if one clicks outside the window somewhere or the close button... I don't want to close colorbox in these cases, instead I want to perform the reload when one HTML button is clicked. So the button should close the colorbox and rise the callback at the same time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make the HTML button reload the page directly. What's the use of closing the colorbox if you'll reload the page anyway?

Comment: I have some form inside the colorbox that makes some database insertion upon clicking on a submit button, so I need to close colorbox and reload the page to see the result.

Comment: Does the submit button do AJAX? If yes, put the page reload into the success handler of the AJAX call.